# openssl/sha.h seems to compute wrong hash

Tags: c, openssl, sha1

I am trying to compute the SHA1 value of a given string in C. I am using the OpenSSL library via `#include <openssl/sha.h>`. The relevant part of the program is below.
 but it shouldn't cause any issues.

```
void checkHash(char* tempString) {
    unsigned char testHash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char* sha1String = (unsigned char*)tempString;
    SHA1(sha1String, sizeof(sha1String), testHash);
    printf("String: %s\nActual hash:   86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8\nComputed hash: ", tempString);
// I verified the actual hash for "a" using multiple online hash generators.
    for (i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        printf("%x", testHash[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Running the program with `checkHash("a");` yields the following output:

```
String: a
Actual hash:   86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8
Computed hash: 16fac7d269b6674eda4d9cafee21bb486556527c
```

How come these hashes do not match? I am running in a 64-bit Linux VM on top of a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. That has caused some problems with poor hashing implementations for me in the past but I doubt that is the issue using the OpenSSL version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(sha1string)` is the same thing as `sizeof(unsigned char*)`, i.e. the size of a data pointer. You want to pass the string's length there, use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`, otherwise you won't be hashing what you think you're hashing.

If `tempString` isn't a null-terminated string but arbitrary data, you need to pass in the length of the data to `checkHash`, there's no way in that case to tell the length from within that function.

Comment: The length was the problem, thanks! Although as a note, `strlen` will not compute an unsigned char*. So using that function will not work here. I just passed in `1` manually to test if that was the problem and it was.